# Dynamically choosing template from a dynamic template path based on session attribute values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 1.5 and  would like templates to be chosen based from a path based on the value in a session variable.

For example, if I have a directory /templates/ which is the root directory of  all templates.
If a session attribute "port" contains  value "2023" I would love for the  root template directory to be changed to /templates/2023/ .
if the session attribute does not exist or the generated root path does not exist, then the root template directory would be /templates/default/ .

How do I accomplish this. Any examples of this solution or solutions to similar problems would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify the template resolver config on the fly then reinitialize it with the new setting. Looking at the source code of [ThymeleafView](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.4.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring4/view/ThymeleafView.java#ThymeleafView.renderFragment%28org.thymeleaf.fragment.IFragmentSpec%2Cjava.util.Map%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29), it forcefully initializes the template engine if it is not initialized yet during the rendering phase of the view itself

```
protected void renderFragment(final IFragmentSpec fragmentSpecToRender, final Map<String, ?> model, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // ...
    // ...
    if (!viewTemplateEngine.isInitialized()) {
        viewTemplateEngine.initialize();
    }
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

This sets the `initialized` flag to true and is checked everywhere when attempting to mutate the already initialized template resolver.

So your best bet is to return the path together with the view name that your controller will ask the template resolver to render

```
// ...
String port = (String) session.getAttribute("port");

return (port == null ? "default" : port) + "/mytemplate";
// ...
```

Your `templateResolver`'s prefix should be set to the parent of all the variable paths which is `templates/`

`templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");`